# Should all my components be placed inside the root App component?

Tags: angular

I'm currently learning to use Angular 4 with angular-cli to build a web front end (well duh).

When I created the app and started mimicking the Heroes tutorial with my own data models, I created a few components, but they - at least the ones showing up at the home page - are all placed inside the root App component. When I `ng generate component`, it's placed inside the App one, which makes me think that's the intented way.

If so, how am I supposed to route the app without the app root component closing? Am I not getting how the components work with routes?

I don't want this question to be too broad, so I'll try to focus on this one bit: how do you build routes that change a component's sub-components, but not the main component itself?

Comment: Short answer: where you place your component in your file structure doesn't generally matter. It has nothing to do with routing :)

Comment: Welp, I've just realized I get *dogshit* of what I read in the docs.

Comment: :D It happens to all of us. But yeah, where you place the components doesn't matter, just when you need to use them, e.g when you define your routes, you just import the component from whatever path it is in. And as for your question about generating components etc, here's how you can change the "default" folder: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services

Comment: with the `assets` folder you need to place your assets there, like JSON files etc, otherwise cli will start complaining to you about not finding such files, but otherwise, do what you like :)

Comment: Just for my understanding, you're wondering why there's one global surrounding component that is always there and on the inside the whole routing process takes places. But the surrounding component never really changes, right?

Comment: (1) Just to clarify, an Angular app can contain multiple modules, and a component belongs to one module. The default module, when you use ng cli, is called "App" (and, the default/first component it generates is also called App.Component), and hence the confusion. (2) The Tour of Heroes example illustrates a simple routing scheme very well, and you should try and understand how they do routing using multiple components (sort of) within App.Component.

Answer (score 0):

actually routing doesn't have anything to do with the placement of components' files inside your app's structure. it's all defined and configured at the `RouterModule`'s `forRoot` and `forChild` methods. check again the docs [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/router).

that being said, don't go haphazardly creating and putting your components and modules inside your structure. first, always check if any given batch of your components and services can be wrapped inside modules. if so, put them together and wrap them inside modules because this really helps with maintaining and scalability of your code. second, check the [angular's own style-guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules) about app's structure.

Answer (score 0):

> how do you build routes that change a component's (say Component A)
>   sub-components (Components b and C), but not the main component (say
>   main.component.ts) itself?

You put `<router-outlet>` in the component (A) and define components B and C as child routes of A

Answer (score 0):

When you add a module using the CLI use the `--routing` flag you'll add a routing module to your feature module: `ng g module feature/Example --routing` that you will be imported into the `ExampleModule`.  When you import the feature `ExampleModule` into your `AppModule` the routes will be added to the application.

Then all you have to do is declare your component routes within the `ExampleRoutingModule` for use within the application using `routerLink`, `router.navigate`, etc.

Finally, by adding `<router-outlet>` to the route component views you can provide sub-component views using the `children` key within your routes.

The code example below includes feature module routing, as well as sub-component routing.  It's quite verbose so I made a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nx8srp?file=app%2Fauth%2Fauth-routing.module.ts) that you can see how it works visually, as well as in implementation.

**Example Module with Routes**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ExampleRoutingModule
  ]
  // ... with whatever component declarations
})
export class ExampleModule { }
```

**App Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Root
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

import { ExampleModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ExampleModule, // Adds your ExampleModule with routes
    AppRoutingModule // WARNING: MUST be the last routing module imported!!!
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Example Routing Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ExampleParentComponent } from './example-parent/example-parent.component';
import { ExampleChildComponent } from './example-child/example-child.component';

const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'example',
    component: ExampleParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', // Equivalent to `/` and alias for `component` to catch provide a default route for `/example` so ParentComponent doesn't display without routed child content
        component: ExampleChildComponent,
        data: { title: 'Example' }
      },
      {
        path: 'component',
        component: ExampleChildComponent,
        data: { title: 'Example' }
      },
      // ...
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(exampleRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ExampleRoutingModule { }
```

**App Component Template**

```
<div class="app-component">

  <!-- 
  Will display the example parent component for a route of
  `/example/component`
  -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

**Example Parent Component Template**

Apply whatever markup or styles you require the example parent component to have that "wraps" the routed child component content:

```
<div class="parent-component special-wrapper-styles">

  <!-- 
  Will display the example child component content for a route of
  `/example/component`
  -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```